# AttributeError: 'Compose' object has no attribute 'Compose' (in Pytorch 0.2.1)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

This is the block of code where am getting this error:

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomRotation(30),
                                       transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
                                       transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
                                                            [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])
```

I've tried updating my torchvision but had no luck!

Comment: how do you import transforms?

Comment: Ensure that you have used `from torchvision import transforms`. Then this should work correctly. Or you can replace `transforms` by `torchvision.transforms` if you use only `import torchvision`.

Comment: @akshayk07 I think I've imported `transforms` correctly. But I tried all other ways too. It still gives the attribute error.

Comment: Try after reinstalling torch and torchvision in a separate virtual environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you have a variable called `transforms` after `from torchvision import transforms` which has a compose of a certain type. This override the transform you import from the `torchvison`. Therefore when you run the above code it calls the transforms which is a `variable` not the one from `torchvision` module.

It is advisable to rename the variable or if you are using jupyter notebook run the cell where you `import transforms` before running the cell with the code above.

Answer (score 1):

```
    train_transforms = torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation(30), enter code here                                      torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),                                       torchvision.transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                   torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                   torchvision.transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
                                                        [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).